# Docker container as daemon

Tags: docker

On my host machine, I have installed docker. Then I pull a Jenkins image.
I want to run that image like daemon service like some services runs on my host machine after rebooting my machine every time. And how can I fix Jenkins port permanent(like 8080) in mine docker?

Comment: You can include the run statement in your `.bashrc` file

Comment: Which `jenkins` image are you using?

Comment: @Ayushya thanks, i'll try.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond I ran this command "docker pull jenkins"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker run -d --restart always -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`

- `-d`: for running the container in background
- `--restart always`: for the container to always restart (unless manually stopped), it will start automatically at boot.

The rest of the arguments are from the `jenkins` [image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/), you may need to adapt your port mapping and volume path.